# How to add trailing slash in every URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

i'm creating a dynamic PHP Blog site, where i have 2 type of url, in where one is having trailing slash and another one is no trailing slash. i want to create trailing slash in each every single url.

> this below url is working properly trailing slash at the end...

```
http://example.com/category/title-of-the-article/
```

> When i navigate to category it's no trailing slash i want to make trailing slash at the end

```
http://example.com/category
```

i want

```
http://example.com/category/
```

**htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ archive.php?category=$1 [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) post.php?category=$1&url=$2 [NC,L]
```

In above htaccess code `post.php` is working fine.... `article.php` is not working.

please help me to make it possible....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bro Htaccess is a thing that we need to debug when we face issue if you put snippet code than we can debug it but as a reader its hard to identify .

but try this one i thing that will solve your problem

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ archive.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hey Bro, i got a in new problem,,,,  i created new rewrite rule -  **`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-\s0-9]+)$ author.php?author=$1 [QSA,L]`**  but when ever i click on this url it's redirect to 1st url..... i.e. archive.php

Comment: didn't get your question

Comment: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-.htaccess-rewrite-rules watch this may be its helpful for you